# PHP Uncaught Error: Call to a member function escape_value() on null

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function escape_value() on null in /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/blog/assets/includes/Library/Misc.php:15

Here is line 15:

```
public static function get_function($func="") {
    global $db;
    $result_array =  self::preform_sql("SELECT * FROM " . DBTP . self::$table_name . " WHERE function = '" . $db->escape_value($func) . "' LIMIT 1");
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `$db` is `null`. Why, we cannot say. There isn't enough details in the question. Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: well its working fine .Only issue with integrate with WordPress header

Answer (score 0):

```
global $db;
//add this to check $db
if (empty($db)) { //better to use instanceof function
    return null; //or do something your: show error | throw exception | else
}
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful